# How to delete a window getter defined with Object.defineProperty

Tags: javascript, object, window, getter

If I do this:

```
Object.defineProperty(window, 'hello',{ 
   get: ()=>"hello to you!"
});
```

which is invoked as:

hello

and replies with 
hello to you!
How do I remove it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add another property to the descriptor object you passed in the `defineProperty`, which is `configurable: true`, after that you can delete the property buy using the `delete` operator.

```js
'use strict'
Object.defineProperty(window, 'hello',{ 
  get: ()=>"hello to you!",
  configurable: true //make this true
});
console.log(window.hello);
delete window.hello
// hello is deleted from window
console.log(window.hello);
```

By default if you don't make the `configurable` as `true` for the descriptor object it is false, from the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#Description):

> **configurable**
>
> true if and only if the type of this property descriptor may be
> changed and if the property may be deleted from the corresponding
> object. Defaults to false.

Comment: So without this is it impossible to delete it?

Comment: @Zibri if you define a new property on an object using `Object.defineProperty` by default it is not `configurable`, so you can't delete it.

Comment: Ok.. I just wanted to be sure of that. Thanks.